# How to make message auto retry when using Rabbitmq and set ttl = 0?

Tags: crash, rabbitmq, ttl

We have a scenario like this:

There may be many workers (a.k.a consumers) in several nodes, at the meanwhile, webapp will submit online jobs to these workers. We need to process these jobs evenly and know if there is available workers to do each single job. Therefore, we want to use Rabbitmq to schedule jobs and set each job message `ttl = 0` to get notice if there is no worker to do each job. But also we want Rabbitmq to handle job rescheduling when worker node crashing. However, if `ttl` is set to 0, Rabbitmq will just drop job message at worker crashing or network failed.

I know we can use DLX to handle dead messages, but it is fussy to build a module to handle these exceptions cause I must make high availability for it. The most important is that I can not distinguish from scheduling failure and rescheduling faiture, which is very different to handle!

Do you guys have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ cannot explicitly know if there are any available workers, consumers that is. It knows how many consumers are consuming the queue, or are connected etc. If you have 5 workers, they will be getting messages in a round-robin fashion, as [described in the tutorial.](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)
For this part

> But also we want Rabbitmq to handle job rescheduling when worker node
>   crashing

simply don't use auto-ACK, rather do manual ACK once the job is finished (actually described in the aforementioned tutorial). If the workers dies, the message is not ACKed and it gets "re-queued".

> The most important is that I can not distinguish from scheduling failure and rescheduling faiture, which is very different to handle!

Now this is a bit complicated and depending on your use case and/or how you want to handle those types of failures. You could simply not ACK, kill the consumer, but then if the message is bad, the next consumer will get it and do the same and then it will go on forever. You could also forward this message (maybe add some additional info) but then the question is what to do with it (maybe log it and that's it?) etc.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But  you didn't get my problem. I need to make message expirable if there is no worker available. but if I set message TTL to 0, the broker just won't re-schedule messages because it will affirm that the re-scheduling messages are expired.

Comment: @JinMa in that case DLX as you mentioned, in my experience it's not really that fussy :)

Comment: yep, I can use DLX and DB to complete my job. but I just want an easier way